# How to implement SharpSerializer's ITypeNameConverter

Tags: c#

the interface only has 2 methods

```
string ConvertToTypeName(Type type);
Type ConvertToType(string typeName);
```

but SharpSerializer is calling my implementation with type and typeName = null
which doesn't make any sense to me

I am trying to use simple namespace.type names (I can not use assembly names in my app due to ILMerge)

Comment: Is your implementation `Type ConvertToType(string typeName = null)`, using the optional parameter?

Answer (score 0):

It was a red herring

It is normal behaviour of SharpSerializer:

```
ConvertToTypeName(null) returns String.Empty
```

and

```
ConvertToType(String.Empty) returns null
```

(You can see this in TypeNameConverter class)

My problem was my implementation of ConvertToType("something valid") was returning null